# C++ list with array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, list

I have to make a list with people and their exam result in C++. My problem is that I don't know how to input the array. 
I was trying to make 3D array of strings, but it doesn't works. **It must be in function!** If you have a better suggestions, I will be very grateful
My input must be something like:
Peter Evens 4.86
*other people** 
*average result of the group** 
*the one with the heighest grade**
*the one with lowest grade**
This is what I have done for now:

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAXN 200
#define MAXM 200
#define MAXX 200
using namespace std;
void input(char list[][MAXN][MAXM], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int p = 0; p < n; p++)
                cin >> list[i][j][p];
        }
}
int main() {
    char list[31][MAXN][MAXM];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    input(list, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since it's C++ why aren't you using actual `string`s?

Comment: Really sounds like you need a data structure that has a name(`std::string`) and result member.  Then you can have a vector of those and you life will be much easier.

Comment: Well, it is homework for school, so I should use only things that I have studied in school.

Comment: Can you provide the exact input that is given?

Comment: The input is:
firstname surname 4.90 
anotherfirstname same 3.84 @ArchieGertsman

Comment: As you are **not** allowed to use such things I would use a C like `struct` in which you declare `name, surname and double`. You can put that in a 1D array and can allocate memory for name and surname as they are `const char*`.

Comment: By list, do you mean a linked list?

Comment: No, just list of names and numbers, @AndreKampling, I will try, thanks.

Comment: Then simply use a vector of pairs

Comment: @Drt they didn't learn std::string and std::vector, but arrays. They have to use them for strings => YAIT

Comment: @Dan Strangely enough most C++ textbooks are arranged in an order that you and I would not approve...I would put that on the teacher, maybe...and for some reason vectors come after strings and arrays.  My beef is the student wanting others to do his homework for him...just saying.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run the third iteration since you don't have to store the input character by character. The third dimension can be used for storing the entire string.

Try the following way. Observe the corrections i have made in your snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAXN 200
#define MAXM 200
#define MAXX 200
using namespace std;
void input(char list[][3][MAXM], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //number of entries
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //3 fields - fname, lname and marks
                cin >> list[i][j];
        }
}
int main() {
    char list[31][3][MAXM];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    input(list, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what flaw you saw in this answer in less than a millisecond so that you forced yourself to downvote it.

Comment: OK but if you insist on doing his homework for him then at least set an example by writing the user prompts and output messages too.

Comment: @Drt. Hello professor, your concerns are quite valid. Here at StackOverflow, we indeed discourage students from posting their homework or assignment questions as is. We only help them overcome the problems they are facing while working on their assignments or homework if they show sufficient efforts from their side. Here, the OP has shown the necessary efforts to demand our help.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I am a bit touchy about such matters.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a vector of struct.

Define your struct this way:

```
typedef struct details{
    string Fname;
    string Lname;
    float marks;
} details;
```

And vector should look like

```
vector< details > info;
```

I am just showing you how to implement this in the following code:

```
void insertValues(vector< details >& info){

    int n;
    details d;
    cout<<"Enter the size of record: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter records: "<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         cin>>d.Fname>>d.Lname>>d.marks;
         info.push_back(d);
    }

}

void LowestScorer(vector< details > info){

    details d;
    vector< details >::iterator it=info.begin();
    d=*it;
    for(;it!=info.end();it++){
        if(d.marks > it->marks){
            d=*it;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Lowest Scorer: "<<d.Fname<<" "<<d.Lname<<" "<<d.marks<<endl;
}
```

main should look like this:

```
    int main(){

    vector< details > info;

    insertValues(info);
    LowestScorer(info);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not tested this code, but I think it should work fine. If any error, poke me.

Comment: He don't must if he is not allowed to. He can use an array and can reallocate  memory. Sure it is C code then, but it seems that this are the constrains. You can implement your own vector class with your limited learned so far stuff.

Comment: @AndreKampling Yeah.. it seems like OP just moved to c++ after learning c. He should introduce himself to the STL. But pointing error are always welcome. Much better way to learn is making errors and correcting them

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above comments, it's good time to learn `vector`. It's very easy. Below is a very simple and neat solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<pair<string, string> > Container;

int main()
{
  Container container;
  container.push_back(make_pair("Peter Evens", "4.86"));
  container.push_back(make_pair("Other name", "his score"));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to use a function

Comment: @VidorVistrom I am puzzled here. There are comments above which suggest the similar thing (vector of strings), and they have got upvotes. I just wrote a working demo for help.

Comment: Your idea is good... Just put it inside a function and implement the requirements...sorting, average and all

Comment: The idea was to help him choosing the data structure. The business logic can be applied on that by the programmer himself. The question did not ask about calculating average, sorting data, etc. :-)